# SQL Server Express usage with Pentaho (or any non-microsoft product)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pentaho

I'm trying to connect a  local SQL Server database to an ETL utility called Pentaho.  Pentaho very easily connects to full versions of SQL server without issue.

I've set mixed mode authentication and created a sql server account for the sql server express instance that can be used to login through SSMS.

When I try to log in via Pentaho, I get errors about it not knowing what the server is, or the server not responding.  I've tried {localhost, myip, localhost\SQLEXPRESS, myip\SQLEXPRESS, just SQLEXPRESS} as the server name (and SQLEXPRESS is the instance name).

I know I've had trouble connecting other programs to SQLEXPRESS databases in the past.  Can someone tell me why it acts different than when using a full install of SQL Server and how I can get around these differences?

Comment: If SQL Server Express is on a different server, have you enabled TCP/IP protocol?

Comment: Toss it up as an answer, I'll check and accept if that's the problem :)

Comment: Check it first, I wrote it as a comment as it's one of these "WTF facepalms" that happen to me all the time. Like read only attributes, basic permissions and stuff like that.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Sorry it took so long I was in a meeting :p It threw me off because I could connect from SSMS using "localhost" but I couldn't connect using JDBC from another program using it.  I guess it did some Microsoft magic in SSMS :)

Comment: Not at all. You can connect locally because it uses Shared Memory protocol, therefore TCP/IP is not needed. :)

Comment: I added the answer, as you asked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SQL Server Express is on a different server, have you enabled TCP/IP protocol?

Comment: Thanks man :) will read up on shared memory protocol, thanks for that tidbit!